# Kosher to setup a D-Star (or DV) repeater on 10m?

Tags: united-states, legal, d-star, band-plan, digital-voice

Equipment availability and other logistics aside, is it kosher in the US to fire up a D-Star (or other digital voice) repeater in the appropriate portion of 10m? I haven't been able to find any indication one way or another so far.

Comment: What's the bandwidths you can use on 10m? That would be the legal limit. The other question would be wether the use case you have for that matches earth dstar or others could do on the resulting channel. For example, if you want to use 10m to get much further reach than on more classical 2m, does dstar also deal well with the resulting larger delay spread?

Comment: The bandwidth of digital voice is comparable or narrower to what analog FM repeaters are using on 10m today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after poking around for a bit I've realized:

- D-Star voice is already a thing on HF, as is Codec2
- FM analog repeaters already operate on 10m FM

There's no reason one couldn't have a D-Star/DV repeater on 10m.

Additional analysis from @Hobbs-KC2G as well (emphasis added):

> The trick is that **97.3(c)(5) includes** F1E, F2E, and FXE (**most kinds of digital voice**) **under the definition of "phone"**, so you should ignore everything about data modes. D-STAR (**DV not DD**) should be fine anywhere "phone" is allowed, and a repeater is allowed where a repeater is allowed. There's absolutely nothing about modes in the definition of a repeater. Just "simultaneously retransmits the transmission of another amateur station".

Comment: I agree. I ran down a rathole looking at 97.305 and 97.307 convincing myself that it *wasn't* allowed, but then, like you, I remembered HF D-STAR. The trick is that 97.3(c)(5) includes F1E, F2E, and FXE (most kinds of digital voice) under the definition of "phone", so you should ignore everything about data modes. D-STAR (DV, not DD) should be fine anywhere "phone" is allowed, and a repeater is allowed where a repeater is allowed. There's absolutely nothing about modes in the definition of a repeater. Just "simultaneously retransmits the transmission of another amateur station".

Comment: (bandwidth limits permitting, of course)

Comment: Thanks for adding your analysis refs to Part 97... I've incorporated into the answer!